# How to find: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(e+x^2)-\cos x}{e^{x^2}-\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate without L'Hospital's rule:  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(e+x^2)-\cos x}{e^{x^2}-\cos x}$

My attempt:

$$e^{x^2}-\cos x=e^{x^2}-1+1-\cos x=x^2\cdot\left(\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}+\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\ln(e+x^2)-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{\ln(e+x^2)-1+1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{e}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{e}\cdot e}+\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(e+x^2)-\cos x}{e^{x^2}-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{e}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{e}}\cdot\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}{\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}+\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{2(2+e)}{6e}$$

Comment: @user64742, why did you delete what I wrote? I wanted to see if it was legitimate.

Comment: Yes your solution is correct.

Comment: I don't see how you get that answer in your last step. Applying the limit as x goes to zero in your last step still gives you an answer which is undefined.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya my apologies, you’re correct. I now agree with PythonSage. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln (e+x^2)-\cos x}{e^{x^2}-\cos x}$$ Let us use
$$e^{x^2}=1+x^2+O(x^4), \cos x= 1+ x^2/2+O(x^4), \ln(1+z)=z-z^2/2+O(z^4),$$
then $$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1+x^2/e-1+x^2/2+O(x^4)}{3x^2/2+O(x^4)}=\frac{2+e}{3e}$$